# HANA DB : How to use CONCAT syntax more than 2 fields

Tags: hana, sapb1, hana-studio

I'm using query in HANA Studio , It's work

```
 CASE WHEN T0."U_XXX_SalEmp2" is not null THEN CONCAT
 (T7."SlpName",CONCAT ('+',T0."U_XXX_SalEmp2")) ELSE T7."SlpName" END
 AS"Sales Emp",
```

But I want to CONCAT more fields

```
**For Example :**  CASE WHEN T0."U_XXX_SalEmp2" is not null THEN CONCAT (T7."SlpName",CONCAT ('+',T0."U_XXX_SalEmp2"),**CONCAT
 ('+',T0."U_XXX_SalEmp3"**),**CONCAT ('+',T0."U_XXX_SalEmp4"**)) ELSE
 T7."SlpName" END  AS"Sales Emp",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the two pipe symbols `||` for chained concatenation.

Your example would look like this:

```
CASE 
 WHEN T0."U_ISS_SalEmp2" is not null 
      THEN 
          T7."SlpName" || '+' || 
          T0."U_ISS_SalEmp2" || '+' ||
          T0."U_ISS_SalEmp3" || '+' ||
          T0."U_ISS_SalEmp4"
 ELSE
         T7."SlpName" 
END         AS "Sales Emp"
```

Comment: I try this but if condition is TRUE  data is empty

Comment: The concatenation (both with `CONCAT` and `||`) will return `NULL` when one of the concatenated values is `NULL`. In your case, `"U_ISS_SalEmp2"` is `NOT NULL` but one of the other values is (if you get `NULL` as the result). To avoid that, you could wrap each value in `IFNULL(<value>, '')`. The `''` is **not** `NULL` but an empty string.  With that, the `NULL`s in your concatenation will effectively be ignored.

Comment: I will try this.Thank you for your advice